# Reach another class variable or control in iphone

Tags: iphone

Hi i will try to explain my problem: i'm working with webservices and i need to give variable or label.text to webservice request wich is in another class... I tried in lots ways, but i can't find solution. I know it must be very easy, but i'm new in objective-c so i have problem in primitive situation. Thanks for everyone who will help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance variable and a property. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html).

In .h:

```
@interface YourClass : Superclass {
    NSString *text;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *text;
```

in .m you have to synthesize it:

```
@implementation YourClass

@synthesize text;
```

now you can set this variable like so:

```
[instanceOfYourClass setText:someText];
```

get it like so:

```
someString = [instanceOfYourClass text];
```

and use it like so (in your implementation):

```
someString = [self text];
```